# Invoking Webhook from GitLab returns SSL error

Tags: gitlab

When creating a Webhook in GitLab 11.0.2 and testing it, I get this back this error:

```
Hook execution failed: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv2/v3 read server hello A: tlsv1 alert internal error
```

The Webhook URI is using HTTPS with a **public** certificate (**not self signed**).

`SSL verification` is disabled for this Webhook.

**Update**

I upgraded `openssl1.0.2g` to `openssl1.0.2o` but the error remains.

Then I tried to run:

```
openssl s_client -connect mywebhookhost:443
```

That resulted in:

```
depth=1 C = BE, O = GlobalSign nv-sa, CN = GlobalSign Organization Validation CA - SHA256 - G2
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
```

**Update 2**

`/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/ruby -ropenssl -e 'puts OpenSSL::OPENSSL_VERSION'`

returns

`OpenSSL 1.0.2o  27 Mar 2018`

**Update 3**

GlobalSign CA certs are installed

```
 awk -v cmd='openssl x509 -noout -subject' '
>     /BEGIN/{close(cmd)};{print | cmd}' < /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt | grep GlobalSign
```

results in

```
subject=OU = GlobalSign ECC Root CA - R4, O = GlobalSign, CN = GlobalSign
subject=OU = GlobalSign ECC Root CA - R5, O = GlobalSign, CN = GlobalSign
subject=C = BE, O = GlobalSign nv-sa, OU = Root CA, CN = GlobalSign Root CA
subject=OU = GlobalSign Root CA - R2, O = GlobalSign, CN = GlobalSign
subject=OU = GlobalSign Root CA - R3, O = GlobalSign, CN = GlobalSign
```

Answer (score 1):

From [this thread](https://forum.gitlab.com/t/trouble-configuring-gitlab-pages-with-tls/10950/2), it looks like your openssl is too old

> Have been fighting with TLS for a few days, realised my GitLab was running on an old debian8, upgraded to debian9. So now.
>
> python -c "import ssl; print ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION"
>       OpenSSL 1.1.0f  25 May 2017

So start checking/upgrading openssl, for your webhook script to run properly.

Comment: I upgraded `openssl` from `1.0.2g` to `1.0.2o` but the error remains.

Comment: @AlexanderZeitler does the test take place your own GitLab server?

Comment: Yes, GitLab 11.0.2 ist running on my own server.

Comment: Is your webhook script written in python? (if yes, see https://git.sickrage.ca/SiCKRAGE/sickrage/wikis/SSL-Errors)

Comment: I'm not using a script but the GitLab Project Webhooks: https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/user/project/integrations/webhooks.html

Comment: OK, so the webhook is a callback calling an https URL. Even though SSL verification is off, the caller (here GitLab) needs to be able to contact a TLS V1.2/1.3. What does `ruby -ropenssl -e 'puts OpenSSL::OPENSSL_VERSION'` return?

Comment: https://mattbrictson.com/tls-error-with-ruby-client-and-tomcat-server: ruby itself, used to run GitLab, might have been compiled with an older version of openssl.

Comment: `ruby -ropenssl -e 'puts OpenSSL::OPENSSL_VERSION` returns `ruby command not found`. I tried grep `openssl /opt/gitlab/version-manifest.txt` which returned `openssl 1.0.2o`

Comment: @AlexanderZeitler Surely if you are on the GitLab server, a `ps -eaf|grep gitlab` will show you a ruby process running that server?

Comment: @AlexanderZeitler I would still check the ruby version used by GitLab. Since you odn't check the certificate anyway, the error message "unable to get local issuer certificate" won't matter much.

Comment: Ruby version according to GitLab Dashboard is `2.4.4p296`

Comment: @AlexanderZeitler right, but with `ps -eaf|grep gitlab`, you can see where ruby is, and then type `ruby -ropenssl -e 'puts OpenSSL::OPENSSL_VERSION'`

Comment: @AlexanderZeitler OK, so the openssl seems to be OK. Remains the certificate itself...

Comment: I checked the certificate using https://sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html which says everything is fine.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem and to solve that i need to install root certificates on gitlab server.

See [here](https://manuals.gfi.com/en/kerio/connect/content/server-configuration/ssl-certificates/adding-trusted-root-certificates-to-the-server-1605.html) how to.

Comment: Shouldn't a CA-Cert from GlobalSign be already installed by installing the `ca-certificates` package?